# A phone number has seven digits and cannot begin with a 0. How many phone numbers contain the sequence 123?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinatorics-on-words

I was going though a course on edx.org and there the instructor counted $5$ different instances like

1. $1 2 3$ _ _ _ _$ = 10^4$
2. _ $1 2 3 $_ _ _ $= 9\times10^3$
3. _ _ $1 2 3 $_ _ $= 9\times10^3$
4. _ _ _ $1 2 3$ _$ = 9\times10^3 - 10$
5. _ _ _ _ $1 2 3 $ $= 9\times10^3 - 10 - 9$

And add all of them. I understood what the instructor did here. But what she did was manually count the exceptions.

Would I also do it manually in case the number of digits are $10 $or $15 $or may be $20 ?$ I think it would be very tedious. There should some standard solution rather than manually revisiting what the exceptions are. What is the standard solution and also explain please?

Comment: Firstly, I ask what precisely is the question: *exactly* one $123$ sequence or *at least* $123$ sequence ?

Comment: The traditional approach is to use the principle of inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: how though for something involving large numbers. may be you could refer to me a more detailly explained video, blog or something @RobPratt

Comment: @SandilAdhikari what does "exacty $123$ sequence " mean ? , did you try to mean "exactly **one** $123$" in the sequence?

Comment: @NotaSalmonFish Out of those 7 digits, three must be 1, 2 and 3 and in the same order, 321 not allowed 132 not allowed and so on. ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to count the words on alphabet $\{0,1,\dots,9\}$ that do not start with $0$ and do contain the word $123$ at least once.  We apply the principle of inclusion-exclusion.

The first term in inclusion-exclusion considers the placement of one $123$.
If the $123$ appears first, there are $10^4$ completions.  If the $123$ appears in one of the other $4$ positions, there are $9\cdot10^3$ completions.  If we stop here, we have overcounted when $123$ appears more than once.

The second term in inclusion-exclusion corrects for this overcount by subtraction.  There are three cases where $123$ appears (at least) twice:

- $123123\_$
- $123\_123$
- $\_123123$

The first two cases yield $10$ each, and the third case yields $9$.

Because $123$ cannot appear more than twice in a word of length $7$, we are done.  Putting it all together, we have
$$(10^4+4\cdot9\cdot10^3) - (2\cdot10+9) = 45971$$
such words, in agreement with the instructor's five cases.

This same approach works for larger numbers of digits, but there will still be some casework to account for the "cannot begin with $0$" rule.

---

OEIS entry [A328916](https://oeis.org/A328916) gives recurrence $$a_n = 10 a_{n-1} + 9\cdot10^{n-4} - a_{n-3},$$
which you can derive by conditioning on whether or not the first $n-1$ digits contain $123$.